# Upgrading Citrix XenServer 5.0 to 5.5

Tags: citrix, xenserver

We're currently running a XenServer 5.0 pool with 3 Hosts. I'd like to upgrade this to 5.5, but am wary to jump right in, so-to-speak.

Wondering if anyone has attempted this in their own environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've upgraded one four member pool from XenServer 5.0 to 5.5 in-place.  I've yet to discover any issues directly related to the upgrade or new version.

The big feature for me was the AD integration and it works perfectly.

Let me know if you'd like any specific information, I'd be happy to oblige.

Comment: Thanks for that.

What sort of level of control do you have with restricting access using AD? Does it just restrict access on a per-host basis, or can you grant access only to individual VMs on a host?

We're in the process of migrating from eDirectory to AD, so I'd be interested about those features.

Comment: In our environment we only need to control full admin access and have not setup any sort of RBAC. I understand that it's possible to do in XenServer but as far as I know only through the web-based Lab Manager console.